# Show an error page 404 if route not found in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

When I putting wrong url I am getting this error, Please suggest me solution of this.

> ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 307: Route [home] not defined. (views\errors\404.blade.php)

I have `404.blade.php` in `resources\views\errors`.

Also in handler.php

```
/*if ($e instanceof CustomException) {
    return response()->view('errors.404', [], 500);
}*/

if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)
    return response(view('error.404'), 404);

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: I have following code in helper.php

Comment: public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        // redirect to form an example of how i handle mine
        return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with(
            'csrf_error',
            "Opps! Seems you couldn't submit form for a longtime. Please try again"
        );
    }

       if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)
        return response(view('error.404'), 404);

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}

Comment: I think in your 404 page you are using route('home') which seems to be not defined. go to routes.php and create a route Route::get('home',function(){ return view('home'); });

Comment: Don't post extending of your question in comments, edit question instead

Comment: @Jagadesha NH, thanks for your help. I have removed 'home' from 404.blade.php, and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your 404 page you are using route('home') which seems to be not defined. go to routes.php and create a route

```
Route::get('home',function(){ 
    return view('home');
});
```

Or remove the route('home') from 404 page